# How to determine what YouTube account a user is logged into?

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api, google-account, youtube-channels

Usecase - your site uses an embedded YouTube player.  The player has full controls so a user can like/dislike a video from the player that is embedded in your site.

Problem - ensuring the account a person is logged into in YouTube and then performs like/dislike actions with is the account you expect.

Is there anyway to determine what YouTube account a user is logged into?

If not logged in at all, Google+ Javascript API's checkAuth() method can determine that.

But let's say a user is not logged in.  You have Auth flow on your site that allows a user to log into their google account.  They log into their account on your site.  So checkAuth() comes back as signed-in.  But then in a new tab, the user goes directly to YouTube and switches which account they are logged into YouTube as.  Your checkAuth() method is going to show that they are signed-in as their original account.

But they will be logged into YouTube as a different account now, and now the actions of like/dislike they perform on videos embedded in a YouTube player on your site will link to their newly switched over account.  And this would be very bad behavior.  We want to ensure that a user is performing actions like/dislike on the account you expect them to, the right account, the one they originally signed in with your auth flow as.

I would love to know how, if there is a way, to determine what account a user is currently logged into YouTube as.

Any help or ideas would be super awesome.  Thanks!